# Airflow. Lost password in connection with DB in UI

Tags: airflow, database-connection

There was a problem setting up the connection with db in UI. For example, I set up a connection with UI, set a password. I'm doing a connection test. Successfully.
But after I close the UI and try to connect through the DAG, the connection is not established, and when checking the connection settings in the UI, the password disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In The UI you can not see the password for security reasons.
If you want to know the full connection parameter then you can run :

`airflow connections export connection.yaml`

this would give you a yaml file with all connection and its parameters (including password)

if you are using docker-compose then you need to enter one of the airflow running container and run this command